# Jersey 2 in WAS 7 REST Client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, servlets

Hi I'm trying to solve a problem from work, but I lack knowledge in this matter. I was hoping someone can give me some light to follow. I'm trying to create a simple REST client do consume some external REST webservices.

My development env.:

Eclipse Luna + Websphere Portal 7 ( WAS 7 ) + JAVA 1.7 + using maven for dependencies.
I'm trying to use Jersey 2 ( latest release don´t know if i was suposed to use jersey 1 )

In my web.xml I have this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>myportal/dataaccess/webservice/rest/myrestclient</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**jersey-container-servlet-core** because i have a servlet-api 2.5

My simple method to get a token i need

```
@GET
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public String getToken() {
    String resposta="";


    System.out.println("STEP 1");
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    System.out.println("STEP 2");
        WebTarget targetnp = client.target(_BASE_URI).path("/login");
    System.out.println("STEP 3");
        targetnp.queryParam("login", _LOGIN);
        targetnp.queryParam("password", _PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("STEP 4");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = targetnp.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
    System.out.println("STEP 5");
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());


    return resposta;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

```
SystemOut     O STEP 1
[25-07-2016 10:22:12:797 BST] 0000003e SystemOut     O STEP 2
[25-07-2016 10:22:12:813 BST] 0000003e ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet RESTtest in application MyPortalEAR. Exception created : java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:76)
```

I can confirm the _BASE_URI is well formed. I do not understand why this is happening.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The param jersey.config.server.provider.packages the values are packages names so you cannot use the "/" you have to use "." (dot):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>myportal.dataaccess.webservice.rest.myrestclient</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If you go to https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/2.0/deployment.html you find examples and information relating jersey.

Also don't forget that in the web.xml you need the servlet mapping, but you have that in the documentation above.

Comment: I found out later that i didn´t need all that dependecies only the jersey-client. I used the 1.19.2 version of it.